# Перевод PHP кода в JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Имеется следующий PHP-код:

```
<?php
    $a = date("W");
    $b = "1 неделя"
    $c = "2 неделя"

    if($a%2 == 0){
        echo"$b";
    }
    if($a%2 != 0){
        echo"$c";
    }
?>
```

Как сделать похожий код в JavaScript?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/ , https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp  Не благодарите!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вам станет от этого немного легче, то так:

```js
var a = new Date().getDay();
var b = "1 неделя";
var c = "2 неделя";
if (a % 2 === 0) {
  alert(b);
}
if (a % 2 !== 0) {
  alert(c);
}
```

Все, что нужно знать - это:

- [Функция date() - вывод даты и времени в PHP](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/date.php)
- [JavaScript Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)